# How can i add two png images in tkinter text widget in sequence?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add two PNG images in tkinter text widget. First one added but second one did not. I got this error :

> _tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=692x904 at 0x2D92D8AF708>" doesn't exist

```
w4_tex_title.insert('end', doc.paragraphs[102].text)
    w4_tex_title.insert('end', '\n'+'\n'+'\n'+doc.paragraphs[103].text)
    w4_tex_title.insert('end', '\n'+'\n')
    cursor1=Image.open('icons//cursor1.png')
    dt_cursor1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(cursor1)
    w4_tex_title.image = dt_cursor1
    w4_tex_title.image_create('end',align=CENTER, image=dt_cursor1)
    w4_tex_title.insert('end', '\n'+'\n')
    cursor2=Image.open('icons//cursor2.png')
    dt_cursor2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(cursor2)
    w4_tex_title.image = dt_cursor2
    w4_tex_title.image_create('end',align=CENTER, image=cursor2)
```

Comment: `image=cursor2` should be `image=dt_cursor2`.

Comment: it did not work.

Comment: Don't just say *"it did not work"*. State what error you got after changing the code.